# Could I continue in my preferred field whilst working on a post-doc in a different field?

Tags: postdocs

I am coming to the end of my present post-doc position which is in a fairly narrow area, one that I am deeply interested in pursuing further.  I am struggling to find a new role in the same area.

What are the implications for someone in this position when i) taking up an unrelated post-doc role, or ii) working in industry until a suitable role comes up?

Some good answers so far, but I would like to extend my original question to:
iii) What are the implications were I to accept a role working in field A, and continue to publish work in field B.  I assume in this instance I would naturally discuss this and only proceed if my primary investigator were happy with it, for example, but could there be other implications/considerations?

Answer (score 1):

There are many whom I know have done their post-docs in a field far different from their primary area of research and work. I don't see this as a problem. Post-docs and PhD dissertation may also widely differ from person to person. I have not seen such a phenomenon affecting their career.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar kind of situation at the end of my PhD dissertation.

1. For your first issue: I often found it very comfortable with my PhD work and I wanted to continue. But, I was not able to find in proper Postdoc Position. I applied several labs related to my research area, however not received any positive response due to several issues like time, research funds availability, contract ends for other Postdoc scholar. I got one response from a lab that does not relate to my field, but got impressed with supervisor. I choose to work with him. Fortunately, I started to work in different field, however, I had always dream to work in my previous work field. I believe that you may find some really good people around you, who are working with the  same area you wanted to work with, are closely related to your current supervisor. Now you can continue to work parallel or start after completion of your current contract.
2. It's upto you, you may find it suitable to work with some academic institutions to continue your research and have some good publications, that may help you to get better Postdoc Position in future. Joining in industry may distract you from research unless the industry is closely related to research.

Comment: Thanks, so the message so far seems to be that the important thing is to continue in academia, and that later on perhaps I can target my preferred area.

One aspect of my question that I should have clarified and will do so now is on how to cross-publish from current position work to my field of choice and the ramifications of doing that. I will update my question to reflect this.